# How to have IntelliJ automatically overwrite files when exporting jar

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, export, overwrite

In eclipse it does it anyway when exporting jars, and will only give a warning unless you tell it not to. However in IntelliJ, it refuses to delete the file when building a new version, and I have to go through and manually delete the jar myself for IntelliJ to export properly. Is there a way I force IntelliJ to overwrite jars when it exports?

Comment: How are you building the .jar? Ant?

Comment: What's that? I'm using Build Artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ always overrides artifacts. Try it again. Make sure no other process is using the file with:
`$ lsof |grep [file name]`

I just tried to make a project with artifact generation, no issues whatsoever.

```
bender:queues_jar demo$ ls -ltra
total 1408
-rw-r--r--  1 demo  staff  718737 Feb 11 21:26 queues.jar
drwxr-xr-x  3 demo  staff     102 Feb 11 21:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 demo  staff     102 Feb 11 21:26 .
bender:queues_jar demo$ ls -ltra
total 1408
drwxr-xr-x  3 demo  staff     102 Feb 11 21:26 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 demo  staff  718737 Feb 11 21:27 queues.jar
drwxr-xr-x  3 demo  staff     102 Feb 11 21:27 .
```